# Changing the charge on a capacitor in an LC circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

I'm working on a problem that asks about doubling the charge on an LC capacitor:

> An ideal capacitor, with initial charge $Q$, is connected in series to an ideal inductor to form a series LC circuit. The oscillation frequency of this circuit is $\omega$. If the capacitor has an initial charge of $2Q$, the oscillation frequency will be...

From what I've learned, $\omega= \dfrac1{\sqrt{LC}}$ and $C = Q/V$. If the charge is doubled, then $C = 2Q/V$ and $C/2 = Q/V$. This would make $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\omega}$ the answer but apparently it is not. Why does the increase in charge not change the oscillation frequency?

Comment: $Q_0$ (I added a subscript 0) is an initial condition, whereas $C$ is a property of the circuit. An LC circuit is like a spring with m->L and k-> 1/C, and displacement $x$ ->$Q$.

A spring does not chance its frequency just because you stretch it more from the begining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitance of a capacitor is based on its physical properties according to

$$C=\frac{\varepsilon A}{d}$$

Where $\varepsilon$ is the absolute permitivity of the dielectric material between the plates, $A$ is the area of the plates and $d$ is the distance between the plates.

For a capacitor with a given capacitance $C$ based on this equation the relationship between capacitance, voltage and charge is

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

Or

$$Q=CV$$

Where $C$ is a constant based on the first equation and $V$ and $Q$ are the independent and dependent variables as written.

So if you have twice the charge you have twice the voltage for a given capacitance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitance of a capacitor is a fundamental property of the capacitor and depends only on the geometry and material of the capacitor. It is the voltage that will change when you change the charge, not the capacitance.